# How to add custom ribbon button in Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, custom-field, ribbon, commands

I am currently using a custom Ribbon Button which has a command attached to it in the Content editor.
I want to create the same ribbon button in experience editor mode and use the same command.

Comment: Does this help your cause: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/customize-the-experience-editor-ribbon.html?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a `custom button` on the `Experience Editor Ribbon`. The requirement was to open a custom popup window by clicking on a button. So for this, I need to use `Sitecore Rocks` to create a button in the `core database`.

Then you need to create a class in your code that will be inherited with `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command`. This will have a method called `Execute` that will again call a `Run` method and here you need to write your logic.

After completing the things, you need to create a `patch file` and provide the entry of your `class` and `assembly`.

Then you have to create a `JS file` in your hosted application folder and it will generate the request.

I have only given you a brief idea that how it is going to be implemented. So I would like you to refer to this blog written by me that contains the step-by-step process to achieve this.

https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/09/02/add-a-custom-button-on-experience-editor-ribbon/

Hope this will give you an idea to complete your task.

Thanks

Comment: Without Sitecore rocks is it not possible ?